# Collapsing values from multiple rows into a single row of generated columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
        x INT,
        y NVARCHAR(30)
)
INSERT INTO @t (x, y) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')
```

Querying that table, I'd like to get this result set:

```
c1   c2   c3
---- ---- ----
a    b    c
```

I know the values of `x` in advance; that is, I know that I want the `y` from the row with `x = 1` as my `c1`, I want the `y` from the row with `x = 2` as `c2`, etc., so I can hardcode those relationships.

How can I get that single row, without using a cursor or a loop?

Comment: Are the values of x finite? Have you looked into the `PIVOT` clause?

Comment: @srutzky: *"Are the values of x finite?"* Yes, and again, I'll know them in advance (e.g., 1, 2, and 3 in the above) *"Have you looked into the PIVOT clause?"* No

Comment: Ok. I see that @Tab did mention PIVOT. It works better with finite values to be converted to columns. It has its pros and cons ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into playing with the PIVOT statement, but I'm not so sure you'll get exactly what you're after.   However, this would also work:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE x WHEN 1 THEN y END) AS c1,
  MAX(CASE x WHEN 2 THEN y END) AS c2,
  MAX(CASE x WHEN 3 THEN y END) AS c3
FROM @t
```